# Taking the matrix derivative of the product of one matrix and a Hadamard Product.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, partial-derivative, hadamard-product

Consider the three matrices $\mathbf{C}$, $\mathbf{A}$, and $\mathbf{T}$. The matrix $\mathbf{C}$ has $\mathit{m} \times \mathit{k}$ entries, $\mathbf{A}$ is a $\mathit{k} \times \mathit{n}$ matrix, and $\mathbf{T}$ is a $\mathit{m} \times \mathit{n}$ matrix.

I'd like to evaluate the following matrix derivative:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{C}}\bigl( (\mathbf{C}\mathbf{A}) \circ \mathbf{T} \bigr)$$

Where $\circ$ represents the Hadamard product. Note that the dimensions of this expression are consistent since $\mathbf{CA}$ is a $\mathit{m} \times \mathit{n}$ matrix. Note that both $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{T}$ are both constant matrices with respect to $\mathbf{C}$.

I'm wondering how I can evaluate and then express this result. I know that since the expression I am taking the derivative of is a $\mathit{m}$ $\times$ $\mathit{n}$ matrix, and $\mathbf{C}$ is a $\mathit{m} \times \mathit{k}$ matrix, that the result of this derivative expression will have $\mathit{m} \times \mathit{n} \times \mathit{m} \times \mathit{k}$ entries.

I'd appreciate any answer, including one in index notation.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Probably the clearest way to express the derivative is to write out the matrix $\frac{\partial }{\partial C_{ij}}((CA) \circ T)$.

Answer (score 1):

Because $C \mapsto (CA) \circ T$ is a linear map, it is very easy to compute the derivative in differential form. In particular, we have
$$
D_C(C_0)(dC) = (dC\,A) \circ T.
$$
Now, let $E_{ij}$ denote the matrix with a $1$ in the $i,j$ entry and zeros elsewhere. Let $e_i$ denote the column vector with a $1$ in the $i$ entry and zeros elsewhere. We have
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial C_{ij}}|_{C = C_0} = D_C(C_0)(E_{ij}) 
= (E_{ij}A) \circ T = (e_ie_j^\top A \circ T) = e_i(A^\top e_j)^\top \circ T\\
= E_{ii} T \operatorname{diag}(A^\top e_j).
$$
In index notation, one might write
$$
\frac{\partial f_{pq}}{\partial C_{ij}} = 
e_p^TE_{ii} T \operatorname{diag}(A^\top e_j)e_q = 
\delta_{ip} e_i^\top T A_{jq}e_q = \delta_{ip} A_{jq}T_{iq},
$$
with no summation implied.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably simpler to [vectorize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products) the matrix equation, and then to eliminate the
Hadamard product in favor of multiplication by a diagonal matrix, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
 F &= T\circ CA \\
 {\rm vec}(F) &= {\rm vec}(T)\circ {\rm vec}(CA) \\
   &= {\rm Diag}\big({\rm vec}(T)\big)\,(A^T\otimes I)\,{\rm vec}(C) \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial c}
   =
\frac{\partial\,{\rm vec}(F)}{\partial\,{\rm vec}(C)}
   &= {\rm Diag}\big({\rm vec}(T)\big)\,(A^T\otimes I) \\
}$$
If you *really* want a fourth order tensor, there is a straightforward one-to-one mapping between the matrix and its vectorized form, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
F &\in {\mathbb R}^{m\times n} \quad\iff\quad
f \in {\mathbb R}^{mn\times 1} \\
F_{ij} &= f_{\alpha} \\
\alpha &= i+(j-1)\,m \\
i &= 1+(\alpha-1)\,{\rm mod}\,m \\
j &= 1+(\alpha-1)\,{\rm div}\,m \\
}$$
So you can convert the gradient matrix into a tensor
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial f_\alpha}{\partial c_\beta}
  = \frac{\partial F_{ij}}{\partial C_{k\ell}} \\
}$$